# linux high performance message passing between threads in c++

Tags: c++, linux, performance, messaging

say i have a process which spawns 2 threads

the first thread listens in a tight loop for packet events on a UDP port.
the second thread is to receive the bytes contained in this UDP packet and parse it/do stuff.

can anyone recommend a faster method than using linux message queues?
i think they are slow because they are copying the bytes upon writing to the queue and copying them again upon reading from the queue

i am aware of the zeromq library but is there a slick way to do this without that overhead?
i realize i could just use a tcp/ip socket between the two threads for simple queued communication but is there a faster way?

i am thinking maybe a ring buffer in memory that is shared between the threads and a mutex used to control a pointer to the most recently updated element?

anyones thoughts here?

Comment: Is this really your bottleneck? Why not use shared memory in threads instead of processes if you're *really* limited by passing that many things around.

Comment: What else have you tried? Unix sockets? Pipes? SysV IPC?

Comment: have a look at http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/: it's java, however, it may inspire you... ;)

Comment: You think they are slow, but slowness is relative to whatever else is going on in the program. *[You should know and be able to use this technique to see what costs time.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/)* The chance is excellent that you have a larger speedup opportunity elsewhere. However, assuming you do, *and you fix it*, then it *might* be that what you are asking about actually is the largest issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient method that I can think of would use one linked list, one mutex, and one condition variable:

- Thread A:

  1. Allocate a udp-packet-buffer object (the object should contain `previous` and `next` pointers, and an array of bytes to store UDP data in)
  2. `recv()` UDP data into the object's byte-array
  3. lock the mutex
  4. append the udp-packet-buffer object to tail of the linked-list
  5. unlock the mutex
  6. signal the condition variable
  7. goto 1
- Thread B:

  1. wait on the condition variable (until the condition variable is signaled)
  2. lock the mutex
  3. pop the next udp-packet-buffer off the head of the linked-list
  4. unlock the mutex
  5. parse/handle the UDP data in the udp-packet-buffer object
  6. delete the udp-packet-buffer object
  7. goto 1

That gives you a zero-copy communications mechanism.  The time spent holding the mutex is minimal, so contention should be low also.

If you wanted to optimize a bit further, you could have thread B grab all of the items out of the linked-list at once instead of just popping off one at a time -- something that is possible to do in O(1) time with a linked list.  And then have thread A signal the condition variable only if the linked list was empty just before it appended its latest udp-packet-buffer object.  That would cut down on the number of times the threads have to lock/unlock/signal when under heavy load.

Comment: this answer is what i was going for; nice usage of the condition variable as i think using the condition variable is better than polling for the mutex lock

Answer (score 1):

This very good answer was what I expected as well, when coming to this page
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567548/2893944

One minor note that could be of help: getting rid of dynamic memory allocations is also a point that could increase performance and avoid memory fragmentation (ex: use a static array, use a memory pool).

(this should have a been a comment, but not enough reputation for that)

Answer (score 0):

checkout http://www.boost.org/libs/circular_buffer/
I use that filled with boost::array<1500> as a communication point between 2 threads in one project and I can not see that it's slow in any way. where the first thread is accepting UDP packages, and quickly by checking some bits if it should place it in the buffer. it does copy in and out but thats not even showing when I profile.

EDIT: the BoundedBuffer example is the interesting bit http://www.boost.org/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#boundedbuffer

Answer (score 0):

For maximum performance you want a fixed size, lockess, single-writer, single-reader queue.

[This codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/LockFree.aspx) turned up in a quick google seems reasonable and explains some of the ins and outs.

I have no idea what your use case is - but if such a lengthy measure is taken - your software (and environment) needs to consider how to deal with the situation where full queue caused by a slow consumer will cause dataloss.

Comment: I do not think term "maximum performance" is appropriate here. That probably would be lowest latency (except the case when there is single thread of course), but for the price of pegging CPU. If it is acceptable tradeoff depends on situation, but I would not call that "maximum performance".